# QtWebEgine add to javascript window object

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebengine

QtWebKit has two methods:

```
void    addToJavaScriptWindowObject ( const QString & name, QObject * object )
void    addToJavaScriptWindowObject ( const QString & name, QObject * object, QScriptEngine::ValueOwnership own )
```

Is there anything similar for QtWebEngine ?

I would like to register a function to the Javascript window object.
Then receive messages from Javascript in the Qt C++ code.

Any ideas?

Comment: i don't think it has one like that. May be you can try something called QWebChannel.js

Comment: Do you have any idea how that works?  looked at the docs but couldn't figure it out

Comment: I just explored that area, but never went hands on. As I vaguely remember, its uses websocket communication to translate QObjects to Javascript world. I think its full duplex and is using QML. Not so sure if they have for c++. Need to look into examples.

Comment: I noticed that you need qwebchannel.js . Is this a file included in the QT framework or something I have to create myself ?

Comment: This is already present in the qt framework. possibly you have to get the latest version of Qt (perhaps qt 5.4). This will by default contain the examples on how to use the qwebchannel. Get some sample example going on and try to play around and tweak it. Later you incorporate into your project.

Comment: I've tried just that but couldn't get any of the examples running properly. They do build and startup but that's it

Comment: I tried on linux machine with building qt from sources . I went and build the examples with; qmake -o Makefile <your-pro-file>.pro This  will generate the build files and then you just start it. post the error that you see when you try to run this command. however, I haven't tried it with qt creator. Even if you use qt-creator; post the application output -- Ill see if i can recollect anything on this.

Comment: It depends on what application it is; may be i tried with some chat example. This will have two builds. you have to run the server part first and then one or two client; They both can talk over using html.

Comment: With some help I managed to get the StandAlone example up and running perfectly. Does anyone know if qwebchannel.js is something that has to be included in every project to be able to use QWebChannel API's ?

Comment: yes, you have to include in all your html files, that needs qwebchannel support.